# loading very large text file into my sql table

Tags: mysql, csv, text-files

I have a very large text file of 6.2 GB. I have loaded this to a table in mysql using 
`load  data local infile 'sample.txt' 
into table table1 fields terminated by ','`
 (It took about 20 mins)But the dump was not successful and the data is not readable and not meaningful. I had a similar file but of smaller size in csv format and could successfully load that into sql table. I am unable to open the large text file, How should I convert the text to csv without opening it? or Can anyone share an idea to successfully load the text file to mysql table

Comment: maybe this might help? http://www.colinwoodhouse.co.uk/txt-csv.htm

Comment: Play around with a subset of the file (first 500 lines, maybe?) until that works, then try working on the whole thing.

Comment: @Marc B What I was thinking is we can only load the entire file into mysql table. Is it possible to load only about 500 rows of a text file into a mysql table? If there is a way like that, please tell me

Comment: @alex: split the file yourself at the command line. On a unix/linux system (or in cygwin), just do `head -500 sample.txt > quicktest.txt` and work off the quicktest.txt file to check if your load infile query is correctly specified. 500 lines of input will be MUCH quicker to test than 6.2jiggabytes.

Comment: @Marc B Ohh thank u..I will try it in cygwin :)